# Python one liner conditional return with for loop

Tags: python

How can I do this as a one liner?

```
def get_sum(a,b):
    return sum(for i in range (a,b)) if a != b else a
```

I tried a few different things but with the for loop I cannot get it to work.

Thanks!

Error:

> File "", line 2
>       return sum(for i in range (a,b)) if a != b else a
>                    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This already looks like one liner.

Comment: it doesnt work though

Comment: What are you trying to make it do? I dont understand your `for i in range(a,b)` statement.

Comment: Given two integers, which can be positive and negative, find the sum of all the numbers between including them too and return it. If both numbers are equal return a or b.

Comment: I was vague sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** OP clarified the intent of the `get_sum` function, and I have adjusted my answers accordingly:

> . . . find the sum of all the numbers between including them too and return it. If both numbers are equal return `a` or `b`.

---

You generation expression should take the form `i for i in range(a, b)` (note the additional `i`):

```
def get_sum(a, b):
    return sum(i for i in range(min(a, b), max(a, b) + 1))
```

An even shorter version would be to forego the generator construct entirely, since `range`s are iterable:

```
def get_sum(a, b):
    return sum(range(min(a, b), max(a, b) + 1))
```

<del>However, I cannot tell exactly what the purpose of your method is . . . is `get_sum(10, 11)` really supposed to return the same result as `get_sum(10, 10)`?</del>

Comment: Ok thanks. I got it to work after seeing this:

def get_sum(a, b):
    mini = min(a,b)
    maxi = max(a,b)
    return sum(i for i in range (mini,maxi+1)) if mini != maxi else maxi

Comment: @michael_b: No need for the `if ... else ...` part: your solution already gives the right value in the case `a == b` without that.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Just what I was going to mention. I had just finished editing my examples to fit the problem description.

Answer (score -1):

With the:

```
    return sum(for i in range (a,b)) if a != b else a
```

you are probably trying to do the following:

```
   ("return sum( range (a,b) ) if a != b else a")
```

Comment: Please check if an existing answer addresses the same points you intend to before posting your own.

Comment: @gyre just to clarify when I started answering at that time there were no answers. thanks